# Adding unlimited integer user input to list and displaying sum in java

Tags: java, list, sum, integer, user-input

I'm trying to get a user to input how long it took them to complete a task in minutes. Depending on if the user repeats the task or not, I want the input to add up to a final integer that shows how long the user took to complete all of the tasks( in this case the same task over and over.) Here's my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entree = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tpsresolution_difficile = 0;
    System.out.println("                                                              ");
    System.out.println("                                                              ");
    System.out.println("         How long did it take you to finish the task?         ");
    System.out.println("                                                              ");
    System.out.println("                                                              ");
    tpsresolution_difficile = entree.nextInt();
}
```

Hope you can help, any input is appreciated!

Comment: mmm, i think it is unclear question can you explain more?

Comment: Of course! The system will ask the user how long it took them to complete a puzzle game for example. The user will have to input a number (representing number of minutes it took them to complete the game). Now the user can replay the game. but every single time the user plays again, the time they say it took them to complete it will be added to the time from the game before. In the end I want to have a mean of the time it took the user to finish a game. I hope this was a bit clearer. If not don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: You'll want to use some sort of loop. You should try to ask a specific question, or this will probably be closed.

Comment: This is the part of the code I was having trouble with but in the grand scheme of things I put a while loop in which if a variable = 0 this code should pop up and if everything checks out variable becomes 1 and exits

Answer (score 0):

Based on your simple example, try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entree = new Scanner(System.in);

    int tpsresolution_difficile = 0;

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("                                                              ");
        System.out.println("                                                              ");
        System.out.println("         How long did it take you to finish the task?         ");
        System.out.println("                                                              ");
        System.out.println("                                                              ");

        int task_time = entree.nextInt();

        // if user inputs -1, stop the loop
        if (task_time == -1) {
            break;
        }

        tpsresolution_difficile += task_time;
    }

    System.out.println("It took " + tpsresolution_difficile + " to finish the task.");
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, please upvote the answer and mark as the correct one. Thx ;)